# How to use this library called bezierjs?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bezier

I have a canvas draw that has curves and I want to know the size of it like one of the examples of this library.

https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs

Example: [Size of a curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBwPh.png)

How can I combine your example with my canvas draw?

This is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

c_size = 650;

ctx.canvas.width  = c_size;
ctx.canvas.height = c_size;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.moveTo(535,105);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(585,44,620,115);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(628,155,643,155);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(628,195,643,360);
ctx.lineTo(550,368);
ctx.lineTo(538,302);
ctx.lineTo(552,285);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(528,195,535,105);
ctx.stroke();
</script>
<canvas id='canvas' width='650' height='650' style="border: 1px solid #000">
Canvas not supported
</canvas>
```

Comment: Added bezier tag.. lets see if not pomax shows up. :-]

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that tries to use Bezier.js for obtaining curve information. Right now you're just using canvas - which is fine, canvas + SVG actually come with plenty of drawing and measurement operations. But also makes this a quesiton about "do you even need Bezier.js? What are you trying to **do**?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am *pretty sure* I give you the API over on [the actual page for this library](http://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/). Like any browser library, include it on your page (this should not need explicit instructions), and then just invoke the library as indicated: create an instance, and then call the api functions described in the online documentation.

Also note that in HTML5, you don't indicate the script type unless it's *not* JavaScript. So:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  ...
  <script src="bezier.js"></script>
  ...
  <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
  ...
  <script src="yourscript.js">?</script>
  ...
</html>
```

And then in your own file:

```
const cvs = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
const size = 650;
cvs.width  = size;
cvs.height = size;
let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

// now do things. Like this:
const curve = new Bezier(/* some coordinates here */);
const p = curve.points,
      p1 = p[0],
      p2 = p[1],
      p3 = p[2],
      p4 = p[3];

// draw the curve
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(p1.x,p1.y);
ctx.curveTo(p2.x,p2.y, p3.x,p3.y, p4.x,p4.y);
ctx.stroke();

// what do we know about the curve?
let len = curve.length();
let bbox = JSON.stringify(curve.bbox());
let msg = `The curve has length ${len} and bounds ${bbox}`;
document.getElementById('infopanel').textContent = msg;
```

Note that Bezier.js is **not** itself a drawing library, it is a maths library for working with Bezier curves. Canvas has quadratic and cubic curve drawing built in (as does the SVG pathing instruction set). Bezierjs is a support library for "getting information about your curves" like their arc length, LUT of on-curve points, intersection computation, etc.

Comment: 2 years later and I'm having the exact same problem trying to understand the code. I really do appreciate the effort put into the library, cannot complain. But man, it's hard to understand the code. I tried to read the index.html sample code, but the script type="text/beziercode" block code is cryptic. No idea how the draw function should be triggered. The sample code does not show clearly how the library should be used in normal browser environment.

Comment: You mean https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs/blob/master/js/draw.js? Most of the abstractions are there because you shouldn't need to care about what _they_ do, only about how use each API section's API function. That said, questions and comment about bezierjs itself should definitely be posted on https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs/issues, not here.